# How to restrict a column not to be reordered in a table that is created using ngx-datatable but all remaining columns must be reorderable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

i am creating some tables using ngx-datatable tool in angular 4. i need one column ie. first column of that table must  not be reorderable and all other columns must be orderable. can anybody help me out?

Comment: Do you mean you do not want your first column to be 'sortable'? E.g. no sorting of the first column when you click the header?

Comment: no.  i mean first column must not be swappable with any other column. the position or order of the first column must not be changed.

Comment: Alright , i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make use of the `draggable` input property binding.

I believe on your component.html, your ngx-datatable component looks something like this. For the first `ngx-datatable-column` you will  need to set the `draggable` property of the first column as `false`. As for the other columns, you can set `draggable` as true, though draggable is true by default, hence there is actually no need to specify it.

```
<ngx-datatable #table class="bootstrap" [columns]="dataColumns">
  <!-- First column is not draggable -->
  <ngx-datatable-column [width]="30" [draggable]="false">
                            ...
  </ngx-datatable-column>
  <!-- The other columns are draggable -->
  <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let column of dataColumns| slice:1; let i = index;" name="{{column.name}}" prop="{{column.prop}}" [draggable]="true">
  ...
  </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

And on your component.ts, you will need to define your `dataColumns`.

```
dataColumns = [
    {
      prop: 'id',
      name: 'ID'
    },
    .
    .
    // other column definitions

]
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. we have already tried this. but the problem is , whenever we drag any other column on to first column, the first column is automatically swapped with other column's position

Comment: Oh my.. I just discovered this issue too. I don't think I have a solution for that. Maybe you should post this on their github page instead? Create an issue, or feature-request?